# Pass dynamic content to bootstrap modal 3.2

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

What i'm trying to do is to pass the data-id value to an external link via JQuery ajax.
The modal will show up but the data-id attribute is not sending to the external link. I think something is wrong with my Jquery script. But i can't find it.

This is my link:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="1" onclick="showAjaxModal();" class="btn btn-primary    btn-single btn-sm">Show Me</a>
```

This is my Jquery ajax script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showAjaxModal()
        {
            var uid = $(this).data('id');

            jQuery('#modal-7').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});


            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "test-modal.php?id=" + uid,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    jQuery('#modal-7 .modal-body').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
```

This is my code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-7">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Dynamic Content</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                Content is loading...

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

---

I want to load the content of the page found by test-modal.

The code of test-modal.php is simple, see below:

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['id'];
echo id: '. $uid;
?>
```

I have tried to make a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dp12ft8/3/ but it's totally not working.
I have changed the js code but it will still not work.

I see the modal showing up but only the word 'undefined' is showing up and not the content of the external file.

Comment: Post a JS Fiddle / JS Bin / live example of your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2dp12ft8/3/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dont mix `onclick` attributes with event handlers, its messy and can cause errors (such as mistaking the scope of `this`, which i believe is you main issue here).

If you are using jquery make use of it:
First add a class to the links you want to attach the event to, here i use the class `showme`:

```
<a href="#;" data-id="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-single btn-sm showme">Show Me</a>
```

Then attach to the click event on those links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
         $('a.showme').click(function(ev){
             ev.preventDefault();
             var uid = $(this).data('id');
             $.get('test-modal.php?id=' + uid, function(html){
                 $('#modal-7 .modal-body').html(html);
                 $('#modal-7').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
             });
         });
    });
</script>
```

To access the variable in php:

```
$uid = $_GET['id']; //NOT $_GET['uid'] as you mention in a comment
```

Comment: @ Steve: Thanks again for helping me. It's working but the modal load is very slow. It takes 2 seconds at least when showing up. Can i do something about it?

Comment: For some reasons i need sometimes 2 vars (uid and something else). How about the javascript? var uid = $(this).data('id'); var test = $(this).data('id2'); and for the get something like $.get('test-modal.php?id=' + uid + 'id2=' + test, function(html)... ?

Comment: The obly thing that will effect the speed is how quickly your server responds to the request, the javascript is fine. To send multiple parameters, your code is almost correct, you just need to seperate them with an ambersand: `test-model.php?var=1&var2=2;`

Comment: Yes i see. My mistake. I know that. First of all i will update my query and then 1 have another question how to use a form with submit inside the modal. I will let you know when i updated my question.

Comment: @BrechtS It is considered bad practice to edit a question on StackOverflow so that it completely changes. You should create a new question, then i will revert this one back, and look at answering your new one

Comment: @ Steve: I will keep that in mind. That's new for me here. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641086/save-change-button-inside-bootstrap-modal-3

Comment: No problem. I have reverted this question and will look at the new one. FYI the reason it is advised not to completely change a question is that all questions on SO are supposed to be useful for future visitors. If you change a question completely, and answers you received prior to the change wont make any sense to anyone except yourself

Comment: I've tried this with the same code, which works but is there a way to make the call from a table item? eg: <tr class="showme "data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">stuff<tr>

Answer (score 1):

Try the **[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** method instead.  I'm taking a guess here, but it seems like you want to actually load the contents of the page found at test-modal.php.  If that's correct, replace your ajax call as follows:

```
function showAjaxModal()
    {
        var uid = $(this).data('id');
        var url = "test-modal.php?id=" + uid;
        jQuery('#modal-7').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
        jQuery('#modal-7 .modal-body').load(url);

    }
```

If your test-modal.php page contains more than a fragment (e.g., it has html and body tags), you can target just a portion of the page by passing an id of the containing element for the content that you want to load, such as:

```
jQuery('#modal-7 .modal-body').load(url+' #container');
```

which would only load the contents of the element with the id container from your test-modal.php page into the modal-body.

Comment: You got it. I want to load the content of the page found by test-modal.

The code of test-modal is simple, see below:

<?php
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
echo id: '. $uid;
?>
I have tried to make a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dp12ft8/3/ but it's totally not working. I have changed the js code but it will still not work.

I see the modal showing up but only the word 'undefined' is showing up and not the content of the external file.