# Add php while in javascript var

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to make some charts with dxcharts. Now i have the following situation:

My SQL query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT
av.art_title,
SUM(CASE c.cont_status WHEN 'cold' THEN av.art_views ELSE 0 END) cold,
SUM(CASE c.cont_status WHEN 'lead' THEN av.art_views ELSE 0 END) lead,
SUM(CASE c.cont_status WHEN 'prospect' THEN av.art_views ELSE 0 END) prospect,
SUM(CASE c.cont_status WHEN 'lost' THEN av.art_views ELSE 0 END) lost
FROM article_views av
JOIN contacts c ON av.user_id = c.id
GROUP BY av.art_title";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

I have a while loop on the query like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { }
```

And below i will post my javascript var:

```
var dataSource = [{ country: "<?php echo $row['art_title']; ?>", lead: <?php echo $row['lead']; ?>, lost: <?php echo $row['lost']; ?>}, ];
```

So if i use the while in the datasource var it's not working at all.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Are you using inline javascript?

Comment: You're dumping text from PHP into a JS context - you're vulnerable to the JS equivalent of sql injection attacks. **ALWAYS** output via `json_encode()` so you're generating syntactically correct JS strings.

Comment: is it a misspell `art_titel` ? instead of `art_title`

Comment: I have updated my code. But still not working.

Comment: It's inline javascript here, Colin.

Comment: Have you verified that your PHP and SQL are returning the expected results?

Comment: Yes. The query is ok. I have tested this in a html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $data[]=array('country'=> $row['art_title'], 'lead'=> $row['lead'], 'lost'=> $row['lost']);
}
$json=json_encode($data);

//javascript
var dataSource=<?php echo $json; ?>;
```

Comment: It's not working. I have this in my javascript: var dataSource = <?php echo $json; ?> But i don't have the brackets [ ] Is that the problem?

Comment: What does the generated output look like? Are you getting any js errors I  the console?

Comment: The chart is not showing up. No errors so far as i can see.

Comment: Now it's working here. The var datasource has to be a ; at the end. Steve, you forgot that. Do you have experience with dxcharts? I have a wrong sorting on the argumentaxis.

Comment: @BrechtS Oops, yes i missed that (typing code into a smartphone is not simple!). I dont have any direct experiance with dxcharts but if you explain your issue i might be able to help

Comment: I have posted this on the dxcharts support. It's a specific issue for dxcharts, i think. Thanks for sharing your earlier post with me. I appreciate that.

Comment: Steve, maybe you can help me with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517605/pass-dynamic-content-to-bootstrap-modal-3-2

Comment: @BrechtS Sure, i wrote an answer (and just amended it). Also if this answer helped you, please mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the original MySQL extension is now deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php , and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi (or PDO_MySQL) extensions.

The E_DEPRECATED error will not be displayed probably on the production server, but it will be generated anyway and it takes time.

So the while loop will look like:

`while ( $row = $result -> fetch_array ( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
...
}`

If you writing a new PHP application, - use the MySQLi.