# Save button inside bootstrap modal 3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

If i click the "change" button in de modal, they will close and nothing is updated in my database.

First of all, the data should be updated in the database and after that i want to show the user that the data is saved. Then the user can press the 'close' button on the modal of click anywhere to close the modal outside the modal frame.

This is my link for opening the modal:

```
<a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn btn-primary showme">Show Me</a>
```

This is my Jquery ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
     $('a.showme').click(function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();

         var uid = $(this).data('id');
         var uid2 = $(this).data('id2');

         $.get('test-modal.php?id=' + uid + '&id2=' + uid2, function(html){
             $('#modal-7 .modal-body').html(html);
             $('#modal-7').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
         });
     });
});
</script>
```

This is my code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-7">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Dynamic Content</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                Content is loading...

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The code of test-modal.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id2 = $_GET['id2'];

require ('config.php');

     $conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($dbnm) or die (mysql_error());

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM historiek WHERE id = '". $id ."'";
     $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
     ?>

      <div class="row">
        <form role="form" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control ckeditor" id="editor10" name="historiek" rows="10"><?php echo $row['historiek']; ?></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-info">Change</button>
            </div>

        </form>
      </div>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];
$historiek = $_POST['historiek'];

require ('config.php');

     $conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($dbnm) or die (mysql_error());

     $sql = "UPDATE historiek SET historiek = '$historiek' WHERE id = '". $id ."'";
     $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: The post handling code in `test-modal.php` will never get used, as the page is loaded over ajax, and the form within it has no target attribute, therefore when submitted it will post to whatever page it has been loaded into (eg if the modal is shown on home.php, the form data will be posted to home.php)

Comment: How you fix this is dependant on what behaviour you want - what do you want the user to see happen when they click submit?

Comment: The editor is loaded with information from the database. The user can change this and click 'submit' to save the new data in the database (update). But if i click on the 'submit' the modal closed and nothing changed in the database. I have updated my code because the 'save' button on the modal is not used. Only the 'submit' button in the test-modal.php

Comment: Sure, I understand what you want to do (save data), and why its not working (as per my 1st comment) but what i dont know is what the user is supposed to see? Should they be redirected to a new page? Or should the modal just close? Or perhaps the modal should show a message like "data saved"?

Comment: The best way is showing the user that the data is saved. After that, the user can press the 'close' button on the modal of click anywhere to close the modal outside the modal frame. I have updated my question.

Comment: @ Steve: Did you see my answer?