# Prevent a click from loading a website and load some other custom content instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project where a user can click on a link to get some additional information about it. The website uses Bootstrap Framework if that is important., The extra information is stored in a file on the server. Here is the code that calls the function `openModal`:

```
$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal);
```

This is the JavaScript code for this function:

```
function openModal() {
  var link = $(this).attr("href");
  var page = "url-of-current-page";
  var text = $(this).text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/getdata.php",
    data: {
      link: link,
      page: page
    },
    success: function(content) {
      $(".modal-body").html(content);
    }
 })
};
```

This is supposed to set the HTML of `modal-body` to the data I received back. But it loads up the actual `link` inside the modal after showing up my data briefly. How can I prevent that?

Let me know if I need to add more details before downvoting.

Comment: `function openModal(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Comment: Use the event object passed through the click event like so: 
`eventObject.preventDefault();` on line 1 of your function.

Comment: @JAG That did not have any effect on loading of other website and my own data has stopped showing at all.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517605/pass-dynamic-content-to-bootstrap-modal-3-2

Comment: @ThED Can it be a problem with `$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal);` because I get an error about undefined `e` while using  `$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal(e));` and  `function openModal(evt) { evt.preventDefault() ...`

Comment: It should be just `$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal);` <- you don't have to change that part.

Comment: @adeneo  Could you please take a look at the URL directly if I send you a message in chat room? I think I am not explaining the issue correctly.

Answer (score 6):

As you're clicking an anchor, you probably want to prevent it from redirecting, change the function to

```
function openModal(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var link = $(this).attr("href");
  var page = "url-of-current-page";
  var text = $(this).text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/getdata.php",
    data: {
      link: link,
      page: page
    },
    success: function(content) {
      $(".modal-body").html(content);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Let me try that :)

Comment: It prevents my own data from loading up. The modal is now completely blank.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh - then your ajax call doesn't work, and no data is gotten.

Comment: If the AJAX call does not work, how can I get the data correctly after removing `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Because the page redirects to somewhere else, isn't that the issue here

Comment: can we discuss this in a chat room if you have some spare time? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120834/discussion-between-sanjeet-singh-and-adeneo).