# How to pass dynamic data from html data-attribute to a query using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, custom-data-attribute

I have this button that hold data from database

```
     <button title="View Conversation" type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#viewConversationModal'
             data-empproj_id="<?=$employeeproject['emproj_id'];?>"
             data-empprojconvoid="<?=$employeeproject['convofeed_id'];?>"
             **data-empprojconvotoempid**="<?=$employeeproject['toemployee_id'];?>"
             **data-empprojconvofromemip**="<?=$employeeproject['fromemployee_id'];?>"
             data-empprojconvoconversation='"<?=$employeeproject['conversation'];?>"' >     
     </button>
```

I need to use the data inside a query

```
    <?php
     $toemployee =  data-empprojconvotoempid
     $fromemployee = data-empprojconvofromemip

    $convoQ = "SELECT * FROM projects as p 
    JOIN employeeprojects AS ep ON p.project_id = ep.project_id 
    JOIN employees AS e ON ep.employee_id = e.employee_id 
    JOIN clients AS c ON p.client_id = c.id 
    JOIN employeeprojects_conversation AS epc ON ep.employee_id = epc.toemployee_id
    WHERE epc.toemployee_id=**$toemployee** AND epc.fromemployee_id=**$fromemployee**"; 
   $displayConvoResult=mysqli_query($db, $convoQ);

;?>
```

then make a while statement to display conversation in the modal

```
<?php while($conversation=mysqli_fetch_array($displayConvoResult)){ ?>
<div class='row convorow'>
<div class='col-md-6 pull-left'>
<p style="font-size: smaller;">Messenger A :</p>
<textarea readonlyrows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6 pull-right'>
<p style="font-size: smaller;">Messenger B :</p>
<textarea readonlyrows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ;?>
```

script so far

```
$('#viewConversationModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(con){
var button = $(con.relatedTarget);
//get data
var empprojconvotoempid = button.data('empprojconvotoempid');
var empprojconvofromemip = button.data('empprojconvofromemip');
});
```

Comment: How are you submitting the data? Html form? Ajax request?

Comment: @Steve: Actually the data gets displayed in a modal... I will use the two variables inside a while statement to display the conversation between the people. I have updated my question with what I have so far.

Comment: @SebastianFarham But how is it getting from the modal to PHP? Is it normal form submission or an AJAX request?

Comment: @Barmar: It is getting from normal form submission... but this is NOT to send data but to DISPLAY data inside the modal.

Comment: You need to understand the request lifecycle - by time you see the button rendered in your browser, php has stopped. All the model code does is show/ hide a bit of the generated html. If you need to have php run based on user action, you need to make another request to the server

Comment: See an old answer of mine that shows how this can be done using ajax and bootstrap modal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517605/pass-dynamic-content-to-bootstrap-modal-3-2/26635298#26635298

Comment: @SebastianFarham The question says you need to use the data inside a query. The query runs from PHP, so you have to send the data from the modal back to PHP.

Comment: @Steve: This could def be it. Do you mind showing by example using my variables so that I truly get it? I'm new and I need to see.

Comment: @Steve: In your other answer you pass the variable to a different page doing `$.get('test-modal.php?id=' + uid, function(html)`. It's not quite the same in my case I stay on the same page. The modal is not on a different page.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity:

- PHP runs in the ***Back-end***
- JavaScript, HTML run in the ***Front-end*** (Browser)

Now to send the data to the server from the Front-End you can do something like:

```
$("button").click(_ => {
    const me = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location,
        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {
            empprojToId: me.attr("data-empprojconvotoempid"),
            empfromEmIp: me.attr("data-empprojconvofromemip"),
        },
    })
})
```

#### Edit:

It seems in your case, that you would rather have the button perform a normal post and render the entire page again with the modal, and new conversations?

If so, then you can put all your data in a html form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="empproj_id" value="<?=$employeeproject['emproj_id'];?>">
    ...
    <button type="submit">
</form>
<!--Insert Modal Code here-->
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: That is good stuff but not quite what I want to do. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should send data from html to php. Since html running on client side (in the browser) and php file executing on server side.

PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Simplest way, using jQuery:

```
<button id='buttonWithData' {data-attributes}></button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var data = $('#buttonWithData').data();
    $.ajax('urlOfYoursPhpFile', {
      async: false,
      data: data
    });
</script>
```

You can then catch data in your php file using `GET` array.

Beware of SqlInjection working with GET and POST arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery selectors to get the data from the attributes and then send it throught ajax.`var dataarray += $("button").attr ("data-...")` get all the data in an array or variables and then `$.ajax ({ data: {"attrdata" : dataarray} , type: "POST",target="callback.php", sucess: function (data){ $("#modal").html(data);} });`